# List division between list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this code that generates two lists.  One list goes from `1-30` and the other goes from `30-1`.  How can divide each element of `some_list2` by each element of `some_list`.  It would be something like this: `1/30`, `2/29`, an so on.  I was thinking about storing each division value in a new list -- one division, one new element.

Here is what I have:

```
some_list = []
some_list2 = []

for i in reversed(range(1, 31)):
    a = i
    some_list.append(a)
for x in range(1,31):
    b = x
    some_list2.append(b)
```

I tried dividing one list by another as a whole, and I looked at a separate for loop for division, but I am stuck.  I am doing this for practice by the way.

Comment: For the record, the code you have written could be simplified to `some_list = list(range(1, 31))`, `some_list2 = some_list[::-1]`. You're performing redundant work even if you must build by iterating and `append`ing (assigning to `a` before `append`ing is silly, when you could just `append` `i` directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension by `zip`ing the lists together, unpacking the tuple elements and dividing:

```
r = [i/j for i,j in zip(some_list2, some_list)]
```

this essentially creates tuples of `(some_list2[i], some_list[i])` values, assigns them to `i` and `j` and then performs the division.

`r` is now a list holding the results:

```
print(r)
[0.03333333333333333,
 0.06896551724137931,
 0.10714285714285714,
 0.14814814814814814,
 0.19230769230769232,
 ...
 4.166666666666667,
 5.2,
 6.75,
 9.333333333333334,
 14.5,
 30.0]
```

Alternatively, you could also do this in a functional fashion, with `map` and `truediv` from the `operator` module:

```
from operator import truediv

r = list(map(truediv, some_list2, some_list))
```

`truediv` is a callable form of the `'/'` operator and is defined for usages such as this one. `map` will take elements from `some_list2` and `some_list` and apply them to the `truediv` function; wrapping in a `list` call is done to expand the map result to a list.

Comment: I like it!    Thanks for the detailed answer.